# Error with button not fulfilling function in rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning rails, currently I am trying to build a tinder prototype to learn the key concepts of rails.

I have run into a stupid stumbling block, currently I have a page for "browsing", I have the js set up and there are no errors on the chrome console but when the buttons to approve and decline are clicked there is no action.

I cant find the reason for this can any one help me?

I have attached my js and html.erb file below

```js
$(function(){  
var $activeSlide = $('#slides .slide:first-child');

     // show first slide 
  $activeSlide.addClass("slide showing");

$("#decline").on("click", function(){
    goToSlide('decline');

});


$("#approve").on("click", function(){
    goToSlide('approve');

});


function goToSlide(action){
$activeSlide.removeClass("showing");

 
         // send data to controller
        if(action == "approve"){

        } else {

   }


    $activeSlide.addClass("showing");




    //slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    //currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
    //slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
 }
});
```

```css
<ul id="slides">
<% @user.each do |user| %>
<li class="slide" data-id="<%= user.id  %>">
  <%= user.username %>
</li>
  <% end %>

</ul>

<button class="controls" id="decline">No</button>
<button class="controls" id="approved">Yes</button>
```

Comment: Where is that javascript being used? Is it it in a script tag somewhere, part of the asset pipeline, etc.

Comment: @ellitt I created a browse controller and browse view and this js is being used on that browse view